# python dict and list comprehension used as switch statement - not working as expected

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm having trouble using a Dict and list comprehension as a case statement. I only want the first match - but I'm getting all matches. The dict is rather long, but it looks lie this:

```
categories = {  'rhsa' : 'Red Hat',
            'red hat' : 'Red Hat', 
            '.net' : 'Microsoft .Net',
            'sql server' : 'MS SQL', 
            'microsoft' : 'Microsoft',
             etc..}
```

The function is simple:

```
def vuln_category(vuln_title):
    vuln_cat = ''
    vuln_title = vuln_title.lower()
    try:
      vuln_cat = ''.join([categories[k] for k in categories if (k in vuln_title and len(vuln_cat)==0)]) # ''.join() to convert to string
       if vuln_cat == '':
            vuln_cat = 'Other'
    except KeyError:
        vuln_cat = 'Other'
return vuln_cat
```

What I'm getting is "3rd Party SoftwareVMWareMicrosoftVMWare".  Clearly the "and len(vuln_cat)==0" is not evaluating in the loop as I expected, resulting in every category match concatenating the dict value.

Yes, I can (and have) code it as nested loops as an easy fix, but I'd like to know the right way to fix this.

Python version is 3.4. I'm trying to keep this simple as it is an fugly script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vuln_cat` is only set **after** the list comprehension completes, you can't access the list being built from inside the comprehension.

Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) inside the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) instead, this'll only pick the *first* matching result:

```
def vuln_category(vuln_title):
    vuln_title = vuln_title.lower()
    return next(
        (categories[k] for k in categories if k in vuln_title),
        'Other')
```

The second argument to the `next()` function is a default, used if the generator expression did not yield any results.

Demo:

```
>>> categories = {
...     'rhsa': 'Red Hat',
...     'red hat': 'Red Hat',
...     '.net': 'Microsoft .Net',
...     'sql server': 'MS SQL',
...     'microsoft': 'Microsoft',
... }
>>> def vuln_category(vuln_title):
...     vuln_title = vuln_title.lower()
...     return next(
...         (categories[k] for k in categories if k in vuln_title),
...         'Other')
...
>>> vuln_category('Microsoft SQL Server on .NET')
'MS SQL'
>>> vuln_category('Red Hat RHSA')
'Red Hat'
>>> vuln_category('Mac OS X')
'Other'
```

Comment: Change made and it works perfectly. Kudos my new friend; take a pat on the back out of petty cash. And I learned something new about Python today! Thanks!